# Starting Docker Desktop on Windows 11 fails

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop, windows-11, windows-terminal

When starting Docker Desktop the following error occurs:

Error details: 2 errors occurred: * provisioning docker WSL distros: setting main distro version: running WSL command "wsl.exe -d docker-desktop -u root -e wsl-bootstrap version set main-101757" failed with output "Unsupported console settings. In order to use this feature, the legacy console must be disabled.\r\nError code: Wsl/Service/WSL_E_CONSOLE\r\n": exit status 0xffffffff * checking if isocache exists: CreateFile \wsl$\docker-desktop-data\isocache: The network name cannot be found

Some other solutions suggest updating wsl to latest:
`wsl --update` & then run `netsh winsock reset` with administrator privelages and restart your machine.

This did not work for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says: *"Unsupported console settings. In order to use this feature, **the legacy console must be disabled...**"*

This is related to a command prompt setting:

1. Open a command prompt (`cmd.exe`)
2. Right click on the top bar
3. Select Properties
4. Uncheck "Use legacy console"

Then start Docker Desktop.